# Is it illegal for a police officer to buy lottery tickets?

Tags: united-kingdom, police, england-and-wales, gambling

I work retail and one of my jobs includes upselling lottery tickets. I was told by a police officer (clearly on duty & uniformed) that it was illegal for them to buy one while on duty as it is considered gambling.

Is this true?

This is in the UK, specifically England.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116737/discussion-on-question-by-studoku-is-it-illegal-for-a-police-officer-to-buy-lott).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. There's nothing in neither the [Gambling Act 2005](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/19/contents) nor the [Police Regulations 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/527/schedule/1?timeline=false) specifically preventing police officers from buying lottery tickets (or gambling in general for that matter).

The principal requirement from the Police Regulations is at Schedule 1, para 1 which is to do it (like everything else in life) sensibly:

> A member of a police force shall at all times abstain from any
> activity which is likely to interfere with the impartial discharge of
> his duties or which is likely to give rise to the impression amongst
> members of the public that it may so interfere.

However, there *may* be local force policies in place (regarding lottery tickets) but I doubt it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there were local force policies saying that they couldn't gamble _while on duty_, but that's obviously the police officers problem to keep to these rules rather than OPs problem.

Comment: @DavidW and indeed breaking the rules set out by one's employer isn't automatically illegal, even for police officers.

Comment: @DavidW - there is precedent for this type of thing being externalised. It [used to be illegal to sell alcohol to a police officer in uniform](https://www.popall.co.uk/qanda/serving-a-policeman.aspx) in the UK

Comment: the image of gambling could interfere with the public image aimed for.

Comment: Note also that police officers under cover may need to gamble or drink while 'on duty'.